# Azure Web API database user import & password hash

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API containing the AspNetUsers table. The standard way to add a user is to call the Register method, which inserts a user with their chosen password and hashes it for database storage.

I need to import a list of users programmatically from somewhere else. This will work fine for every field except for the password.  I need to hash it so that the Web API UserManager can read it when they try to log in.

Does anyone know how the UserManager hashes the password and if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per MSDN, the standard [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468199%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) implementation uses [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to hash passwords.

You can use the same to generate hashes which will work with AspNet Identity framework.

Note: If you're wondering if this is same as `ApplicationUserManager` class that newer WebApi uses, then the answer is yes:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
}
```

Reason why they did this is explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/10499038.aspx).